# How Will Ethereum Differ From The Linux Foundation Blockchain?

Tags: linux

What are some crucial advantages/disadvantages to both, and what factors will affect user adoption? Finally, in what ways will they one day work together?

Answer (score 3):

I have been pondering about the same question for a while now. Here are some thoughts:

- it is currently not possible to comment in any detail on the efforts by the Linux Foundation as, since [the announcement in Dec 2015](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/announcements/2015/12/linux-foundation-unites-industry-leaders-advance-blockchain), there has been little further detail on the project charter. The [project page](https://blockchain.linuxfoundation.org/) is still waiting for the curtains to be lifted.
- as a result of the above, its quite possible that the two activities will diverge technically, and while both will deliver an open, distributed ledger platform, they may quite possibly only partially overlap in terms of applicability.
- as you will see from the announcement, the Linux Foundation project is backed by a fairly long list of heavyweights from various industries who will inevitably have differing interests. Of course this is a double edged sword: you can't expect such a project to be the most agile, but the breath of experience could lead to a more robust end-result.
- the Linux Foundation is already respected, well functioning organization that has years of experience running open projects. It is therefore less likely that they will end up facing funding issues, or governance problems.
- Ethereum has the benefit of approx 2 years head-start and agility associated with a relatively small team of independent developers. If you need to start exploring/building something now, then waiting for an outcome from the Linux Foundation may not be an option.

Since the question is fairly broad, there are bound to be more aspects that would warrant mentioning. The above is just one set of perspectives.

Interestingly this however raises a related fundamental question: given that by its very nature, any blockchain's adoption is dependant on [netwrok effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect), having a flurry of disparate blockchains is bound to be problematic in the medium-long term. From that perspective, it is interesting to see how long other industry standardization fora will remain on the back-seat.